# Delete comment without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Would like to know how I can improve this code to enable no page refresh when I delete a comment. As its rather annoying if you delete a comment half way down the page and it reverts back to the top.

AJAX

```
    function delete_(pid){
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "../include/post.delete.php",
       data: "pid="+pid,
       success: function(){
       }
     });
    }

DELETEPOST
    echo'<div class="userinfo"><div id="divider">';

            if($streamitem_data['streamitem_type_id'] == 1||$streamitem_data['streamitem_type_id'] == 3){
                echo "";
                }else{
                echo "";
                }

                $poster_name = _user_core::getuser($streamitem_data['streamitem_creator']);
                $target_name = _user_core::getuser($streamitem_data['streamitem_target']);


            if($streamitem_data['streamitem_type_id'] == 1||$streamitem_data['streamitem_type_id'] == 3){
            if(!($streamitem_data['streamitem_type_id']==1)) {

                echo "<a href='/profile.php?username=".$poster_name['username']."'><img class='stream_profileimage' style='border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;' border=\"0\" src=\"imgs/cropped".$streamitem_data['streamitem_creator'].".jpg\" onerror='this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ></a>";

echo "<a href='/profile.php?username=".$target_name['username']."'><img class='stream_profileimage' style='border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;' border=\"0\" src=\"imgs/cropped".$streamitem_data['streamitem_target'].".jpg\" onerror='this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ></a>";
            }
                if(!($streamitem_data['streamitem_type_id']==3)) {
                echo "<a href='/profile.php?username=".$poster_name['username']."'><img class='stream_profileimage' style='border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;' border=\"0\" src=\"imgs/cropped".$streamitem_data['streamitem_target'].".jpg\" onerror='this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ></a>";

                }
                    $cont = stripslashes($streamitem_data['streamitem_content']);

                    if(!($streamitem_data['streamitem_type_id']==1)){
                    //$cont = htmlentities($cont);
                    $cont = ereg_replace("[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]","<a class='user_link' href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", $cont);

                    }


                    if($streamitem_data['streamitem_creator']==$streamitem_data['streamitem_target']){
                        echo "<a href='/profile.php?username=".$poster_name['id']."'>" . $poster_name['fullusersname']."</a><span class='subtleLink'> said </span>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<a href='profile.php?username=".$poster_name['username']."'>" .$poster_name['fullusersname']."</a>  
                        <span class='subtleLink'>wrote on </span>
                              <a href='profile.php?username=".$poster_name['username']."'>" .$target_name['fullusersname']." 's</a> stream";
                    }
                    echo "<br/><a href='#' class='subtleLink' style='font-weight:normal;'>".Agotime($streamitem_data['streamitem_timestamp'])."</a></div><hr><div style='padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;'>";

                    if($streamitem_data['streamitem_type_id']==1){
                    $cont = nl2br($cont);
                    echo "<span class='subtleLink'>".$cont."</span>";
                    }else{

                        if($streamitem_data['streamitem_creator']==$streamitem_data['streamitem_target']){
                        $cont = nl2br($cont);
                            echo "<div>".$cont."</div>";
                        }else{
                        $cont = nl2br($cont);
                        echo "<div>'".$cont."</div>";

                        }

                    }


        echo "</div><div class='post_contextoptions'>";
    if($streamitem_data['streamitem_creator']==$_SESSION['id']){
        echo "<div class='stream_option' id='delete_option'><form style='display:inline;' id='delete_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."'  action='include/post.delete.php' method='POST' target='ifr2'><input type='hidden' name='pid' value='".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."'><a style='cursor:pointer;position:relative;top:-70px;float:right;padding-right:5px;' onClick='document.forms[\"delete_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."\"].submit();refreshstream();'>X</a></div>";
```

}

Comment: have the success handler delete the comment's dom node?

Comment: How would I go about doing that please Marc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `.remove()` on the comment element you just deleted. You will need to figure out how to identify it. There is one way:

```
function delete_(pid){
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "../include/post.delete.php",
       data: "pid="+pid,
       success: function(){
           // However you can identify the comment's div, and delete it by calling .remove()
           // This is if it has a unique id
           $("#comment-"+pid).remove();
       }
     });
}
```

Otherwise, if you used `<a href="javascript:delete_(pid);">` you could add a parmeter like `<a href="javascript:delete_(pid, this);">`. This way you would get to the element via `$(the_element_you_passed_to_the_function).parents("div.the-comment-div-parent").remove()` for example.

Otherwise you could implement this function right inside the `$("a").click(function {});` if you are using this method. It's up to you.

Comment: Is the comment element the div in which the comment is held inside?

Comment: I've updated my code where my stream post is as I'm not sure what I'm needing to call. If anyone could help please/

Comment: Yes, the div that contains all that you wish to hide should be removed. If you can post a sample HTML output your page produces it would be good, so that we can know what your HTML structure is. It is really unclear what the piece of code you posted produces. I *believe* you should delete the divs with class `userinfo` (matched with `div.userinfo`), but the name does not seem to be relevant, so I'm not sure.